# Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle

Помогите, пожалуйста!!!
Каждый раз как запускаю Intelij IDEA выбивает одну и ту же ошибку:

> Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C:\Users\RooT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Еще и подчеркивает код красным...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, вставте код с картинки в тело вопроса

Comment: покажите ваш build.gradle. кажется у вас ошибка в строке с `targetSdkVersion`

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 4):

Просто скачайте **SDK** для **API Level 26** из **Android SDK Manager**. Ошибка связана с отсутствем платформы, а не с отсутствием какого-либо инструмента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузил новый API,  но Gradle все равно ругаеться... Да еще и другая ошибка вылазит: Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Users\RooT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\bin\java.exe

Comment: @ВадимБашкарев C:\Users\RooT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\bin\java.exe а вы проверяли этот путь ?

Comment: Да, проверял. Система утверждает, что путь не правильный.

Comment: @ВадимБашкарев значит найдите и установите правильный sdk для Android в AndroidStudio, как на первом скрине

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в переменной `JAVA_HOME` указать путь к JDK. На пример, у меня стоит `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_31`.

Comment: Где находится эта переменная?

Comment: Компьютер->Свойства системы->Дополнительные параметры системы->Переменные среды->Ищем в списке если его нет, то Создать->На первой строке JAVA_HOME->На второй путь к JDK. А если есть то пропишем путь к JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) либы поддержки теперь качаются не из SDK, а с гуглового репозитория. Т.е. помочь может указание его адреса в `build.gradle` уровня проекта:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/education/troubleshooting-guide.html#outside_of_known_port_range:

*Windows Firewall*

1. Open Windows **Firewall**.
2. Go to **Advanced Settings**.
3. Right-click **Inbound Rules** and select **New Rule**....
4. Select **Port**.
5. Enter a port range that is used by your IDE of choice, in this case it's **63342-63362**.
6. Allow the connection.
7. Restart your system.

Comment: Ответ переведите на русский ;)