# Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

При сборке *gradle* появляется следующая ошибка

> Error:(69, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

*Android Support Repository* установленный, а ошибка появляется...
Подскажите пожалуйста как устранить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0` - такой версии библиотеки не существует.

`SDK\extras\android\m2repository\` - суппортный репозиторий у Вас в папке SDK - там и можно посмотреть. Последний релиз **25.3.1** ; превью **26.0.0-alpha1**

Comment: подскажите сайт где можно посмотреть последние версии библиотек для gradle? Помню был какой то сайт...

Comment: SDK\extras\android\m2repository\ - суппортный репозиторий у Вас в папке SDK - там и можно посмотреть. Последний релиз 25.3.1 ; превью 26.0.0-alpha1

Comment: Последний релиз уже 26.0.0. Но он теперь не входит в SDK и подключать его надо иначе. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703183/17609